# Will running a signal through a voltage divider change its phase?

Tags: filter, voltage-divider

I'm reading a web page about filters (https://www.sensorsmag.com/components/introduction-to-analog-filters) and noticed something that doesn't make sense.  The web page says if you run a signal through a voltage divider it will change the phase of the signal (here is a screenshot):
[image]

This is confusing to me because my understanding of resistors is that they have only a real part to their impedance which would mean that they don't change phase.  Can someone explain to me how running a signal through a voltage divider will change the phase?

Comment: You're not reading it right. Try to pay attention to what the text is referring to, compared to what the figure shows. The figure comes into play a few lines down (after the mini title `Filter Circuits 101`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. The resistive divider will not affect the phase unless there is a reactive component loading the circuit to the right of V<sub>OUT</sub>.

[image]

*Figure 1. The statement in the article refers to these filters further down the page. Source: [SensorsMag](https://www.sensorsmag.com/components/introduction-to-analog-filters).*

The article could be improved.

Comment: But, there is always stray C to ground (e.g. IC input C), and you should always calculate XC @ Fmaximum, before you discount it. Don't just say -there is no C, so the divider is resistive. That has blown many an AC measurement.